# Is primary objective mandatory for activities?

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I want to know if primary objective is mandatory for activities?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to declare a primary objective for each activity. In fact if you don't declare a primary objective, the LMS will create one for you since the LMS uses the primary objective in the rollup and sequencing  processes. However, if you create local objectives, you have to declare a primary objective in your manifest file.